# Comments and Rating section no longer showing up;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on creating a test shoe store website for one of my classes. I had previously added a comment section and rating system for new shoes. For some reason the comment and rating section is no longer viewable.

Here is my product show page

```
   <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <div class="show-buttons" id="show1">
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product), class: "btn btn-    success btn-xs"  %> |

    <%= link_to 'Back', products_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
  </div>
  <div class="pay button">
  <%= form_tag "/payments/create" do %>
  <%= render partial: "shared/stripe_checkout_button" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:product_id, @product.id) %>
</div>
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @product.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @product.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Image url:</strong>
  <%= @product.image_url %>
</p>

<p>Average Rating: 
  <div class="rated" data-score="<%= @product.average_rating %>"></div> 
</p>

<%= render 'new_comment' %>
    <%= render 'comment' %>
    <%= will_paginate @comments %>  

</div>


<% end %>
```

Here is my _comment.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="product-reviews">
        <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
        <div class="row">
            <hr>
          <p><%= comment.user.first_name %> <small><em><%= "# {time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago" %></em></small></p>
        <% if signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
            <%= link_to ('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">  </span>').html_safe, product_comment_path(@product, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        <% end %>   
        <div class="rated" data-score="<%= comment.rating %>"></div>
        <p><%= "Rating: #{comment.rating}/5" %></p>
        <p><%= comment.body %></p>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

My _new_comment.html.erb

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <h4>Add a review:</h4>
  <%= form_for([@product, @product.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
  <%= f.label :body, "Comments" %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p>
 <%= f.label :rating %><br>
  <div class= "rating"></div>
</p>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>    
</p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And finally my product.html.erb

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

     <div class="productbox">

        <div class="imgthumb img-responsive">
          <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'list_image') %>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3><%= product.name %></h3>   
        </div>

      </div><!--end productbox-->
      </div><!--end columns-->

         <div class="col-md-8" id="descriptionp">
          <p><%= product.description %><br><br>
          <%= product.color %><br><br>
          €<%= product.price %><br><br>
          <%= link_to 'More Info', product %><br><br>

          <% if signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %> | 
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
          <% end %>
         </p>
         </div>    
  </div><!--/row-->  
</div><!--/container -->
<hr>
```

Any assistance on why I can no longer view my comments or rating page would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: render 'new_comment', but the template name is '_new_comments' (plural)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the name of the comment.erb and new_comment.erb pages. However the comments and rating section is still no showing up.

Comment: I figured out the issue after reading your advice again. I forgot to render _product. Thanks for the help.